# Random js error on checkout

Tags: checkout, javascript

I've noticed a strange random JS error on onepagecheckout. Randomly I read this error in console and executions of submit order stops

```
>   POST /onestepcheckout/index/savePost/ 503 (OK)  send @
> ma.jq.slide.js:4  f.extend.ajax @ ma.jq.slide.js:4
>   $.widget._placeOrder @ opcheckout.js:418(   anonymous function) @
> jquery-ui.js:401  $.widget._save @ opcheckout.js:569  (anonymous
> function) @ jquery-ui.js:401  (anonymous function) @ opcheckout.js:105
>   f.event.dispatch @ ma.jq.slide.js:3     h.handle.i @ ma.jq.slide.js:3
```

Comment: ADD: This error occurs only if I try to pay with Paypal, cancel payment and retry to buy another time. If I clear browse cache It works again once and gives error on the second time!